# Why won't Steam work on amd64?

Tags: steam, software-installation

I can't install Steam on my Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit. It says that it's for "i686"; where can I get that? I have tried to install it using the Ubuntu Software Center and from the terminal.

I have seen many videos on YouTube about installing Steam in Ubuntu. Why won't it install on my PC?

Comment: You may need to provide more information to enable us to answer your question.  What graphic card are you using?  This may be a localized issue as I had no issues installing Steam on my AMD64 using the software centre

Answer (score 3):

First of all, i686 is for Intel. Just copy this command and paste in the terminal(ctrl+t), then hit enter

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases fakeroot libqtgui4 lib32gcc1
```

then hit enter, type your password, and hit enter again.

after that, either reboot your computer manually or just type:

```
sudo reboot
```

and try again to download Steam from the Ubuntu Software Center.